# I have started learning Entity Framework, and facing problems. I have a model class, but cannot make an entity framework connection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

This is the model class:

```
namespace MVC_Demo.Models
{
  public class Employee
  {
    [Key]
    public string Name;
    public string Id;
    public string Designation;
    public int Salary;
    public Address Address;
 }

 public class Address
 {
    [Key]
    public string AddressLine1;
    public string AddressLine2;
    public string City;
    public string State;
    public string Country;
    public string PinCode;
 }
}
```

This is the `DbContext` :

```
namespace MVC_Demo.Models
{
    public class EmployeeDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public EmployeeDBContext() : base("name = EmployeeDBContext")
        { }

        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have not done anything else. What else is required to build an Entity Framework connection. Please help me

Comment: Make sure you can connect to the DB using the connection string in your web\app.config with the entry _EmployeeDBContext_

Comment: can you please tell me step by step what else i must do to make an ef connection

Comment: In the package manager console write these commandes 1-enable-migrations ,2 add-migration migrationName, 3-update-database after that your database will be created at EmployeeDBContext connection string

Comment: another fix : EF code first create the datebase "if you did not use the migration commands" at the first use of the context so yout just have to add this lines at Homecontroller.cs  EmployeeDBContext  cntx=new EmployeeDBContext ();cntx.Employees .add(new Employee() ); cntx.SaveChanges();

Comment: This is basic stuff that can be found in any old EF beginner's tutorial.

Comment: I have installed entity framework......next i want to save data.....what should i do next?

Comment: I have installed Word. Now I want to write a novel... Don't you see that your question is a teeny-weeny little broad?

Answer (score 0):

In the "**Package Manager Console**" write these commands one by one
`enable-migrations` 
`add-migration migrationName`
`update-database` 
after that your database will be created at EmployeeDBContext connection string .

Another fix : EF code first creates the datebase "if you did not use the migration commands" at your first use of the context so you just have to add this lines at Homecontroller.cs

```
EmployeeDBContext cntx=new EmployeeDBContext ();
cntx.Employees .add(new Employee() );
cntx.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

add a nuget package reference to the Entity framework.

```
right click on references -> Manage Nuget packages-> search for entity  framework -> install
```

Add connection string in Web.config with same name as your DBContext class.